# Python Telegram-бот

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Создал я бота в телеграм, сделал такой код чтобы мне приходило имя пользователя, когда он нажал /start. Сделал всё правильно, бот без ошибок. Но вопрос куда мне должно приходить имя пользователя?

Answer (score 0):

```
message.from_user.id # ID пользователя.
message.from_user.first_name # Имя в профиле пользователя.
message.from_user.last_name # Фамилия в профиле пользователя.
message.from_user.username # Имя пользователя через @.
```

Comment: Я же спросил, куда должно приходить имя

Comment: Оно приходит, просто вы его не выводите. Можете сделать так: print(message.from_user.username).

Answer (score 0):

Можно создать файл csv, туда и будут приходить имя пользователя

```
def log(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    file = open('db.csv', 'a')
    file.write(f'{update.effective_user.first_name}, {update.message.text}\n')
    file.close()
```

В функции start вызвать log

```
def start(update, context):
    log(update, context)
    context.bot.send_message(update.effective_chat.id, "Привет \n Как дела?")
```

Как только пользователь наберет /start то в файл db.csv будет записана строка в виде имени пользователя и текста который он набрал, это и будет логирование

```
first_name  /start
```

Comment: Можно пожалуйста поподробнее. Мне нужно в папке с config.py и кодом бота в моём случае bot.py создать файл db.scv, и когда кто то напишет там /start, то в файле db.scv тобиш файле Microsoft Office Excel будет появляться имя пользователя и текст которй он написал, верно?

Comment: ды ты попробуй и увидишь

Comment: Я попробовал, ничего не происходит.